# SharePoint Feature - adding reference dll in package?

Tags: feature

I have a feature which is referencing a custom library. How can I include this dll in the SharePoint 2010 package so that it is registered in the gac?

Comment: You need to be careful. If the Assembly is also deployed by another WSP Solution. If that other solution is ever retracted it will remove the Assembly. If you own the Assembly you can manage this lifecycles yourself. If the Assembly is from a 3rd party any other solution might also choose to deploy the assembly to the GAC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double click "Package" select "Advanced" and "Add" additional assemblies

Answer (score 0):

For detailed information you can refer this [link](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/)