# OpenXML and WebPart Solution Deploying to Live Server

Tags: deployment, solution-deployment, openxml

I have the OpenXML SDK installed on my development machine, and I have written a webpart solution that basically creates an excel file using the OpenXML dll. This solution is a full farm solution not a Sandbox solution.

When I deployed on my PC all is ok, as I have the OpenXML SDK installed, and all the revent dll's required for my webpart is in place on my PC. However when I deploy my WSP to the live server, it doesn't have the SDK installed.

How do I ensure the OpenXML dlls are available on the live farm without having to install the OpenXML SDK on each server in the live farm. There must be something I can do within my solution to ensure the dlls are available.

Regards

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the openxml dll is not being deployed on the machine global assembly cache. Make sure your package is configured correctly.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I kept looking at that screen, but wasn't sure. Should have just given it a go.

Comment: No worries. Just remember any external dll should be packaged too. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OpenXML. But if it's this package: [NuGet - DocumentFormat.OpenXml](http://nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) you could first run:

```
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml
```

And then [reference the DLL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/sharepoint-feature-adding-reference-dll-in-package) files in your package.
You will find the DLL files on solution level under *Packages*