# How to use dll file and resource files in Sandbox Solution of SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, office-365

I am currently working with SharePoint Online(**Office 365**), so that i am creating the sandbox solution for creating custom web-parts.
Here problem is that i want to use **Ajax Control Toolkit**(dll) and other dll and resource(**.js,Images,.css**) files.

Is it Possible to use dll and Resource Files in **sandbox solution** (Office 365) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add DLL files as usual. Just run

```
Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit
```

to install the package from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit).
Then reference it as Anders Rask explains here: [adding reference dll in package](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/6101/627).

For resources you could just reference them in a Module (Elements.xml). As far as I know they will be unghosted because of file system restrictions in sandboxed solution. But this should put them at root:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Assets">
    <File Path="Assets\mystuff.js" Url="mystuff.js" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

(Module called Assets).

**Update**:
To use a pure DLL you need to embed your resources within the DLL file and use a Feature Event Receiver to add them to SharePoint.

Here is one solution for embedding the resource: http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/martynbullerwell/archive/2007/11/30/embedding-images-into-dll-s.aspx .
But you could probably use any way you like, even generate some classes with Base64 strings (ugh).

Then you use any FileCollection method which support bytes, such as [SPFileCollection.Add Method (String, Byte[], SPUser, SPUser, DateTime, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439259.aspx)

Comment: For js file its correct but it not work for DLL

Comment: Oh my, I completely missed that. But I think you can actually do this with a pure DLL as well